# Qt: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'realloc', qvector.h

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qvector

I have a problem, including some QtCore libraries in my project. I am using CMake and Visual Studio Qt 5.15. In my CMakeLists.txt I include QtCore like this:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

target_link_libraries(${projectName} PRIVATE Qt5::Core)
```

Then I add `#include <QtCore/qvector.h>` in my code and some errors will show up:

```
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qvector.h(103): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'realloc'
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qvector.h(316): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qvector.h(327): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'QVector<T>' being compiled
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qvector.h(411): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'realloc'
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qvector.h(420): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'realloc'
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qvector.h(700): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qvector.h(700): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qvector.h(1071): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'realloc'
```

This errors will appear even if I include only `<QtCore/QFileInfo>` or `<QtCore/QDir>`. But When I include `<QtCore/QString>` or `<QtXml/QDomDocument>` this errors won't show up.

I tried deleting CMake cache, but with no result. This problem has started since migrating from Visual Studio solution to CMake.

Comment: I don't know whether this will fix the problem, but usually Qt headers are supposed to be included without a directory and file extension, e.g. `#include <QVector>` instead of the internal `#include <QtCore/qvector.h>`. Needing to add a the `QtCore`/`QtXml`/... prefixes usually indicates a missing `target_link_libraries` call for the respective library. It is entriely possible that the `QVector` file includes some other necessary headers before including `qvector.h` which could explain these problems.

Comment: Soneone introduced a define for realloc in a header that is included prior to `#include <QtCore/qvector.h>`. As you don't show what is included before, it is hard to guess.

Comment: Adding only ```#include <QVector>``` did not change anything. And my previous includes include for example <queue>, which yes, in fact leads to vector->xmemory->cstdlib and there is declared realoc. So what could be the sollution here?

Comment: What I meant was someone defined a **macro** named realloc that gets in your way, not the function or using declaration of realloc. Those is perfectly valid.

Comment: This thread is quite ancient but shows one possible reason for your error. https://forum.qt.io/topic/822/_crtdbg_map_alloc-macro-and-qt/2

Comment: Well the link do not lead to anything. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Just noticed that the link is broken, but the Qt bugtracker contained a similar  entry https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40575?focusedCommentId=334524&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

Comment: the use of #pragma_pop/push worked but, there is another errors: ```qlist.h(466): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'n'; qlist.h(464): note: while compiling class template member function 'void QList<QString>::node_construct```, I dont think this is the right way to do it, since in other projects the include is doing just fine

Comment: The reason this happened was, redefinition of new keyword. I had to do push/pop macro for new keyword as well. I am not sure why this happens only with this specific project, but anyway thanks.

Comment: Pushing the realloc macro does not directly address the problem caused by the partial overloading of the new operator. Either limit new redefinition to the relevant part of your project or provide a complete redefinition for new. My guess is that you get syntax error for this line within qlist.h : if (QTypeInfo<T>::isComplex) new (n) T(t);