# qlist.h(466): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'n'

Tags: c++, qt, include

I have a problem including Qt libraries to one of my projects. The includes are:

```
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtXml/QDomDocument>
#include <iostream>

#pragma push_macro("realloc")
#undef realloc
#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <QtCore/QFileInfo>
#include <QtCore/QDir>
#pragma pop_macro("realloc")
```

Includes  `QFile` ,  `QFileInfo`  and  `QDir`  cause this error:

```
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qlist.h(466): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'n'
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qlist.h(464): note: while compiling class template member function 'void QList<QString>::node_construct(QList<QString>::Node *,const T &)'
      with
      [
          T=QString
      ]
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qlist.h(625): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void QList<QString>::node_construct(QList<QString>::Node *,const T &)' being compiled
      with
      [
          T=QString
      ]
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qlist.h(854): note: while compiling class template member function 'QList<QString>::QList(const QList<QString> &)'
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qstringlist.h(117): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'QList<QString>::QList(const QList<QString> &)' being compiled
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qstringlist.h(112): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'QList<QString>' being compiled
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qlist.h(505): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'current'
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qlist.h(487): note: while compiling class template member function 'void QList<QString>::node_copy(QList<QString>::Node *,QList<QString>::Node *,QList<QString>::Node *)'
C:\qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qlist.h(860): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void QList<QString>::node_copy(QList<QString>::Node *,QList<QString>::Node *,QList<QString>::Node *)' being compiled
```

The push/pop macro is used because of similar error with realloc template, which was resolved here: [Qt: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'realloc', qvector.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815188/qt-not-enough-arguments-for-function-like-macro-invocation-realloc-qvector-h?noredirect=1#comment118112617_66815188).

Comment: This is very strange. I just added those #includes to one of my .cpp files and it doesn't complain about anything (I removed the realloc stuff). What version of Qt do you have installed?

Comment: I have Qt 5.15.0. I think they fixed something like this in Qt 6.0.0 (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86395). But there has to be some other problem since in my other project it is working fine.

Comment: I'm also on 5.15.x

Comment: The reason this happened was, redefinition of new keyword. I had to do push/pop macro for new keyword as well. But thanks.

Comment: The order of your includes might clean this up, depending on where that keyword is. Is it your code that redefines realloc? That seems particularly scary.

Comment: Only realloc uses the redefined new? Pushing realloc alone will not solve your problem. Most likely the redefinition of new is incomplete. Provide a complete redefinition of new.

Comment: Problem is that "placement new"  is not compatible with re#define-d new.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990880/replacing-new-with-macro-conflicts-with-placement-new
Both problematic lines in qlist.h contain new with placement pointer:
`new (n) T(t); // qlist.h 466`
and somewhere you may find a macro like this:
`#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)`
`#define new DEBUG_NEW`

Comment: I already resolved it by rearanging the positions of the includes, but Thanks Pavel.